# How to copy and paste always one row below

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on code to copy and paste from one worksheet to another. The data that I need to copy will always be at `A1:E1`, however, I need to always paste one row below. I will run it everyday, so for instance if today I paste on cells `A1:E1`, then tomorrow I would need to paste on `A2:E2` and on the next day `A3:E3`... I wrote the code below which works but is not as dynamic as I need it to be. I would appreciate your help

Thank you

```
Sub Copy_range()

Worksheets("Dividends").Range("A1:E1").copy

Worksheets("Draft").Range("A1:E1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make it more modular by skipping down past all used cells then pasting the value on the next empty cell.

```
Sub Copy_range()

    ' edit line below to change where data will be copied from
    Worksheets("Dividends").Range("A1:E1").Copy ' copy the value

    ' select the first cell on the "Draft" sheet
    Worksheets("Draft").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

    Dim count As Integer
    count = 1

    'skip all used cells
    Do While Not (ActiveCell.value = None)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
        count = count + 1

    Loop

    ' edit line below to change alphabetical values of where data will be placed
    Worksheets("Draft").Range("A" & count & ":E" & count).PasteSpecial ' paste the value
    ' at Acount:Ecount where count is the current row i.e. A11:E11

End Sub
```

Comment: it worked, thank you! If i want to paste on cell C11:N11 instead, which part of the code should i change?

Comment: No problem!  Do you mean in your own code as a one-time thing?  If that is the case, then change     Worksheets("Draft").Range("C" & count & ":N" & count).PasteSpecial    Also, only if you're satisfied with the answer, would you mind selecting answer/upvoting to close off the question?

Comment: I mean, i need to do exactly the same.. but pasting on cell C11 to N11 on sheet "Draft" instead of a1:e1, where would i have to change? I changed the part you said but it did not work

Comment: Whoops.  You can change your own code on the following line:    Worksheets("Draft").Range("C11:N11").PasteSpecial End Sub   All that is being changed is pasting to C11:N11

Comment: Ok, now it works, but when I run again it doesnt paste on the line below..c12:n12

Comment: Running my code?  To paste on one cell, simply change the CX:NX value in your own code.  To paste under a cell with different letters, change the corresponding letters in my code.  I.e. Worksheets("Draft").Range("C" & count & ":N" & count).PasteSpecial

Comment: Would you mind to send the code again? I have tried the possibilities and it didnt work. What I need is: Copy from sheet "dividends" cells E2:P2 and paste on "draft" cells c11 to n11, then do it again and paste on cells c12 to n12...

Comment: I have edited my code.  Change the values for where you want to copy and where you want to paste as I have indicated.  If you want to do it one time, just change the ("A1:E1").copy to ("E2:P2").copy and ("A1:E1").PasteSpecial to ("C11:N11").PasteSpecial

Comment: I change it and it still copy on the wrong cell, i think the problem is on the last line but I dont know how to solve it