# How To Paste My Formula In A Cell With Specific Text Instead Of A Column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I pretty much have an already working macro for me but for the future it may cause problems because the macro i have finds the column i gave it and then starts to input the formula there. Now my data may change in the future and in that column i might have something new so the macro would obviously run the formulas to the wrong column. Changing it manually is possible but hectic and a lot of work. Is there any possible way i can select a cell with a specific text in it instead of the column? since the text will never change this will me much easier for me to work with. Because doing this the formulas will always be posted in the correct column.

EDIT! I added the whole code to the post so you can see it more clearly and understand what i mean more clearly.

```
Sub HW_Copy_RawData_Formulas()
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim I As Integer
Dim filePath As String
Dim SourceWb As Workbook
Dim TargetWb As Workbook
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Nrow As Long

Set TargetWb = ActiveWorkbook
' Delete Rows
On Error Resume Next
    TargetWb.Worksheets("Raw Data").Activate
    Range("A2:AL2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A2:AL2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
'Copy Formulas
Range("AF2").Formula = "=IF([@ServDt]<DATE(2013,1,1), DATE(YEAR([@ServDt]),12,31),EOMONTH([@ServDt],0))"
Range("AG2").Formula = "=IF([@Amount]>1,[@Quantity],0)"
Range("AH2").Formula = "=IF([@Amount]<>0,[@Amount]-[@Adj]-[@[Adjustment ]],0)"
Range("AI2").Formula = "=IF(AND([@Department]=""HH"",[@Pay]=0),[@Amount]/2,0)"
Range("AJ2").Formula = "=IF([@Amount]<>0,[@Bal]-[@[Adjustment ]],[@Bal]+[@Adj])"
Range("AK2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP([Department],Service[#All],2,FALSE)"
Range("AL2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP([@Entity],Site,3,FALSE)"

MSG1 = MsgBox("Add Raw Data", vbYesNo)
If MSG1 = vbYes Then

'only allow the user to select one file
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
'make the file dialog visible to the user
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
'determine what choice the user made
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
    'get the file path selected by the user
        strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
            msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
     Else: GoTo endmsg
    End If

'Setting source of data
Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

Lastrow = SourceWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

SourceWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:BJ" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2")
' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
SourceWb.Close savechanges:=False

Else
endmsg:
  MsgBox "Complete"
End If

Range("AF2:AL2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AF2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet might be of use to you.  It acquires the range of the cell given a specific value.  It can also be used to search a specific row with `.Rows()` instead.

```
Dim *YOURCELL* As Range

Set *YOURCELL*= .Columns(1).Find(What:= *WHATYOUWANTTOFIND*, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
```

If, however, you do not know where the last used cell is located, then consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790049/how-to-copy-and-paste-always-one-row-below/30790299#30790299) other post.

EDIT:

The while loop runs as long as the currently selected cell is not empty.  In this loop, it selects the next cell to the right and increments a count.  After the loop has finished, the currently selected cell is the first empty cell in the second row.  Count has found the column number of it by incrementing alongside the loop, so it can then be used as needed.  I used cells instead of range afterwards because it can use the column number.

```
Range("A2").Select    

Dim count As Integer
count = 1

'skip all used cells in the row
Do While Not (ActiveCell.value = None)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    count = count + 1
Loop

Cells(count, 2).Formula = your_formula
Cells(count + 1, 2).Formula = your_formula ' next cell to the right
Cells(count + 2, 2).Formula = your_formula ' next cell to the right
```

Comment: I dont think thats exactly what i was looking for. i added my whole macro there so maybe you can understand better. Like where it says Range("AF2") i wanted to know if it was possible to say like SelectCell("Service Date") Yes i know i completely made the SelectCell but its to use as an example

Comment: Can you explain a little bit on what the edit is used for? like a small explanation would be nice so i can follow through and try it out.

Comment: Explanation has been added.  I hope it helps!